# How to display debug error in xamarin vscode?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

When attempting to redirect to another page on my xamarin app, if there is a runtime error in the xaml page that I am redirecting to or the constructor for the view model, the page doesn't redirect but it also does not display any error and sits on the same page. Is there a way to debug this in vscode like I would with the chrome debugger console?

A stack trace or something along these lines to find out what the problem is would make life a lot easier.

Comment: Can you show the code causes the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the `InitializeComponent();` of this page in the try-catch block and process the error.

Comment: This doesn't work. The Initialize component isn't throwing an error. I know exactly which line of code is preventing the redirect and it seems to be a service I'm injecting into the constructor of the view model. When I remove it the page redirects. I'm just not sure why the service is failing.

Comment: Create the viewmodel manually before InitilizeComponent inside the wrapper?..

Comment: Turns out I wasn't injecting the service but this answer effectively answers my original question of how to debug a xaml page. Accepted answer. Thanks Nick.